# Using JTable to display ResultSet

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, vector, jtable

I'm learning about JDBC with GUI. I can do that the GUI display the data in SQL one by one. Then i want to display the data in table just like the result when i execute in SQL. I saw that many people use two Vector to add data to JTable. I wonder is there anything else apart from Vector that I can do to add data to JTable.I really want to add some images in my post but i can't so sorry if it's uncovinient for everyone. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder is there anything else apart from Vector that I can do to add data to JTable.

The `DefaultTableModel` uses `Vectors` because it makes the `TableModel` dynamic. That is you can easily add or remove rows/columns from the model.

If you don't want to use a Vector then you can create a custom `TableModel` to store the data any way that you want.

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). It gives an example

1. of how to create a custom TableModel using an ArrayList for the data
2. of to write a generic TableModel that is reusable

Comment: Does ArrayList is easy to add, remove or edit the data in JTable ?

Comment: @aUsUd, The TableModel controls whether you can add/remove rows of data or edit the data. Read the Swing tutorial on `Creating a TableModel`. I provided a link to the tutorial which explains in detail how a JTable works.